# Apache Multi-project configuration

Tags: linux, apache, subdomain

I have a server with an ip: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

In my server, i have several projects in the folder /var/www:

```
/var/www/project1
/var/www/project2/trunk/webroot
...
```

My 000-default.conf is like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Currently I access into them through the following url:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/project1
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/project2/trunk/webroot
...
```

I have a domain that targets to my server

```
domain.com -> XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

My intention is to create a subdomain for each project, and each subdomain points to the target folder of the project:

```
project1.domain.com   -> XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/project1
project2.domain.com   -> XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/project2/trunk/webroot
```

(I think the best solution will be that XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/project2 targets directly to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/proyect2/trunk/webroot)

I have read that it will be great that each project has its own .conf file in apache, and enabling each site separately.

But I think that if I create a VirtualHost *:80 for each project (project1.conf, project2.conf) they will be in conflict and I dont know how to do it.

Can anybody help me?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Host is the way to go... create one virtual host for each domain pointing to a folder on your server where to webpage is sotored.

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org
</VirtualHost>
```

Etc... One VirtualHost for each domain / DocumentRoot convination

Soruce: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

##################### EDIT

I have tested it on my own server

Whithout touching the default.conf file I have created two new config files

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2/sites-available# pwd
/etc/apache2/sites-available
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2/sites-available#
```

Please ignore the default files I have not touched them I have just created two new files named project1.... and project2....

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2/sites-available# ls
000-default.conf  project1_domain_com.conf
default-ssl.conf  project2_domain_com.conf
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2/sites-available#

root@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2/sites-available# cat project*
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/projects/project1/"
    ServerName project1.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/projects/project2/"
    ServerName project2.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2/sites-available#
```

ENABLING SITES

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2/sites-available# a2ensite project1_domain_com.conf
Enabling site project1_domain_com.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2/sites-available# a2ensite project2_domain_com.conf
Enabling site project2_domain_com.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2/sites-available#
```

RELOAD APACHE

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2/sites-available# /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
[ ok ] Reloading apache2 configuration (via systemctl): apache2.service.
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2/sites-available#
```

################# SUBDOMAIN EDIT

For example I have a single server with an IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX that have multiple domains registered (15 domains now).

I have one virtual host entry for each domain that works this way:

domain1.example.com -> Load the domain1 web index.html page (without /nothing/else ) 
domain2.example.com -> Load the domain2 web index.html page hosted on another folder expecified on the second virtual host.

And finally ussing a2ensite or a2dissite I enable or disable the website as a web hosting provider do...

If for any reason you need that accessing the host domain3.something.com it redirects to domain3.something.com/something/diferent ... it should be done on your server ussing .htaccess file and its a entirely diferent question :D

Comment: In your case you can create a new someting.conf on /etc/apache2/sites-available for each domain. Then execute  a2ensite someting.conf
for each configuration file. That way you keep your conf file separated and more organized

Comment: I don't understand where can I assign the "/project2" in the VirtualHost for accessing XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/project2
Will be in the ServerName?

Comment: I have this on my 000-default.conf :
http://pastebin.com/raw/GxYtqiBn

And trying to restart apache, I got this:
 * Restarting web server apache2
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
   ...fail!
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems

Comment: Could be this due having 2 virtualHost in the same port?


I understand that first I need to create an alias (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/project2) targeting XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/project2/trunk/webroot and then, I have to create a subdomain (project2.domain.com) wich targets the recent created alias (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/project2)

But I can't create a subdomain that targets XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/project2 because this is not a valid CNAME (or A)

Comment: Hello, 
See my edits... you should not put listen 80 no the new files... Check the edits

Comment: Note that this way the alias project1.domain.com will be accessing the path /var/www/html/project1 (or whateaver you have set) and the other domain will access the other path on the server.

But absolute path without /project2

Comment: Note that when creating the CNAME or A name you should poing only to your ip address ... Le the web part to the virtualhost file and the .htacccess file..

Comment: Your pastebin is ok if you delete the line with Listen 80. But its better if you do that ussing separate files as I have explain you.